# How to get expiry date of azure storage accounts keys by az commands?

Tags: azure, cmd, azure-storage, az

Trying to get expiry date of azure SaaS keys like "media storage, blob", followed Microsoft's online docs, still not finding, please help me if anyone knows that command...

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is that there's no az command for that. Storage keys don't expire. In order to make them unusable, you just have to regenerate those keys. Once a key is regenerated, the old key automatically expires and becomes unusable.

Comment: Thank you sir, for the information!
Have a question: if we set the expiry date of 6 months, how can i get it by az cmd? i mean is there any way to see that?

Comment: Simple answer is that you can't set an expiry date for a storage account key. Are you talking about Shared Access Signature (SAS) URL expiry?

Comment: No no, not SAS URL, talking about SAS keys expiry dates

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean by SAS key?

Comment: They don't expire :)

Comment: Just one last question, inside media or blob storage, we have containers, so for those containers can we get expiry date?

Comment: What do you mean by container's expiry date?

Comment: I mean, for each container we may have secret keys right? so for those key if we can get expiry date?

Comment: Nope. You have the same key for all containers in a storage account. Are you sure you're not talking about SAS Tokens?